# how can I upload a kml file with a script to google maps?

Tags: python, google-maps, gdata, gdata-python-client

I have a python script, that generates kml files. Now I want to upload this kml file within the script (not per hand) to the "my maps" section of google maps. Does anybody have a python or other script/code to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:** You can't until [issue 2590](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2590) is fixed, which may be a while because Google have [closed this issue as WontFix](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2590#c13). There are workarounds you can try to achieve the same end result, but as it stands you cannot simply upload a KML file using the Google Maps Data API.

**Long version:**

I <strike>don't</strike> didn't have any Python code to do this, but the [Google Maps Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/) allows you to do this with a series of HTTP requests. See [Uploading KML](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#uploading_kml) in the HTTP Protocol section of the [Developers Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide.html) for the documentation on how to do this. So one possible Python solution would be to use something like [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) in the standard library to do the appropriate HTTP requests for you.

After various edits and your feedback in the comments, here is a script that takes a Google username and password via the command line (be careful how you use it!) to obtain the `authorization_token` variable by making a [ClientLogin authentication request](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#ClientLogin). With a valid username and password, the auth token can be used in the `Authorization` header for POSTing the KML data to the Maps Data API.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import httplib
import optparse
import sys
import urllib

class GoogleMaps(object):
    source = "daybarr.com-kmluploader-0.1"

    def __init__(self, email, passwd):
        self.email = email
        self.passwd = passwd
        self._conn = None
        self._auth_token = None

    def _get_connection(self):
        if not self._auth_token:
            conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.google.com")
            params = urllib.urlencode({
                "accountType": "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
                "Email": self.email,
                "Passwd": self.passwd,
                "service": "local",
                "source": self.source,
            })
            headers = {
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Accept": "text/plain",
            }
            conn.request("POST", "/accounts/ClientLogin", params, headers)
            response = conn.getresponse()
            if response.status != 200:
                raise Exception("Failed to login: %s %s" % (
                    response.status,
                    response.reason))
            body = response.read()
            for line in body.splitlines():
                if line.startswith("Auth="):
                    self._auth_token = line[5:]
                    break
            if not self._auth_token:
                raise Exception("Cannot find auth token in response %s" % body)
        if not self._conn:
            self._conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("maps.google.com")
        return self._conn

    connection = property(_get_connection)

    def upload(self, kml_data):
        conn = self.connection
        headers = {
            "GData-Version": "2.0",
            "Authorization": 'GoogleLogin auth=%s' % (self._auth_token,),
            "Content-Type": "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml",
        }
        conn.request("POST", "/maps/feeds/maps/default/full", kml_data, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        if response.status != 200:
            raise Exception("Failed to upload kml: %s %s" % (
                response.status,
                response.reason))
        return response.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-e", "--email", help="Email address for login")
    parser.add_option("-p", "--passwd", help="Password for login")
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    if not (options.email and options.passwd):
        parser.error("email and passwd required")
    if args:
        kml_file = open(args[0], "r")
    else:
        kml_file = sys.stdin
    maps = GoogleMaps(options.email, options.passwd)
    print maps.upload(kml_file.read())
```

**Unfortunately**, even when using valid login credentials to obtain a valid authorization token and using a valid KML file containing exactly the example as given in the documentation, the API responds to the KML post with a `400 Bad Request`. Apparently this is a known issue ([2590](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2590) reported July 22nd 2010) so please vote for and comment on that if you'd like Google to fix.

In the meantime, without that bug fixed, you could try

1. Create the map without uploading KML, and then upload KML features as appropriate, as suggested in [comment #9 on the issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2590#c9) from Google, when they confirmed that the bug exists.
2. [uploading XML](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#uploading_xml) or [uploading CSV](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#uploading_csv) instead of KML if these methods support what you need to get done
3. fiddling with the format of your KML data. [This post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-data-api/msg/c34efa7fef259e0f) in the Google Group for the API suggests that this might help, but it looks complicated.

Good luck

Comment: sorry, but I get a
400 Bad Request
Bad request
and I don't know how to debug this.

Comment: @Jörg Beyer Strange. You normally only get a 400 if the request is not a valid HTTP request for some reason. I've updated my answer, please give the script a go, should be runnable as is.

Comment: I still get a "400 Bad Request". I am confident, that the auth-token is OK, because I get a 401 when I modify my freshly generated token.

Comment: @Jörg Beyer: Perhaps Google doesn't like your KML and thinks it's invalid? Are you using your own or my example? Note I haven't actually had time to try my script with my a real auth-token, may do tomorrow. Keep trying ;)

Comment: You've probably checked already, but what does the body of the 400 response say? Does it give further details on the error?

Comment: no, it just repeats the "Bad Request" - any ideas about further debugging?

Comment: @Jörg Beyer: Ok, so it looks like this is a known problem with the API/docs! See http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2590 and please vote for the issue (star it) and/or add your comments there to help push it along. You may have more luck uploading XML or CSV if your problem doesn't require KML to solve? I'll update my answer again with my latest code which I've now fully tested with a real google loging which also gives me the 400 error :(

Comment: Looks like Google are responding to the issue now, so please work through your specific problem with them there and please please report back here when you have a fix or workaround ;)

Comment: Google have now confirmed the issue and suggested a workaround: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2590#c9

Comment: Google have today set the status of this bug to WontFix https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2590#c13. Best let them know if you feel otherwise.