# Importing 'my maps' from google account to my own application

Tags: android, maps

my question is short.

I am making an application that creates and uses .kml map files. I thought it would be a very good idea if the user could upload his maps to Google "My maps" server (which imports .kml files through the browser version) from my application, and also load them afterwards. However, I have not found any documentation related to this possibility, and I have spent hours looking through the internet and the Google Maps Android API, without luck.

Does anyone know if my idea is possible? Or google keeps this closed for their internal applications?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API to upload .kml files to Google Maps (the [Google Maps Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/)), but it doesn't work due to [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2590) that Google have decided not to fix for some reason.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816541/how-can-i-upload-a-kml-file-with-a-script-to-google-maps/3816655#3816655) to the question "[how can I upload a kml file with a script to google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3816541/445073)" for the details

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! 

What a pity, I guess I will have to leave that feature out by now... :(

Comment: @petoria No problem and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry it wasn't better news for your first question. Please consider accepting my answer if you found it helpful. Thanks